# Show $||A||_2=(\sum\limits_{i,j=1...n} a^2_{ij})^{(1/2)}$ defines a Matrix Norm

Tags: matrices, inequality, matrix-norms

> Show $$\def\norm#1{\left\lVert{#1}\right\rVert_2{}}\norm A ={\left(\sum_{i,j=1\ldots n} a^2_{ij}\right)}^{1/2}$$ defines a Matrix Norm for $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$

to show: $\norm{ AB}\le \norm A \norm B$

If i use Cauchy-Schwarz

$\sum a^2_{ij}\sum b^2_{ij}\ge(\sum a_{ij}b_{ij})^2$

but it is not always the case that;

$(\sum a_{ij}b_{ij})^2\ge\sum (a_{ij}b_{ij})^2 $

Comment: I think, it is $||A||_F$, and not $||A||_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $C=AB$ then $c_{ij} = \sum_t a_{it} b_{tj}$.  Hence

$$\|AB\|_2^2 = \sum_{ij} \Bigl(\sum_t a_{it} b_{tj} \Bigr)^2 
{\color{Red}\leq}
\sum_{ij} \sum_t a_{it}^2 \sum_t b_{tj}^2
=
\sum_{it} a_{it}^2 \sum_{jt} b_{tj}^2 = \|A\|_2^2\|B\|_2^2,
$$

where the red inequality follows from the Schwarz inequality.

Comment: $\|AB\|_2^2 =\sum_{ij} \Bigl(\sum_t a^2_{it} b^2_{tj} \Bigr)$ or not ?

Comment: No, it isn't.  The square should be outside the sum.

Comment: Is not $\|AB\|_2 =\Bigl(\sum_{ij} \Bigl(\sum_t a^2_{it} b^2_{tj} \Bigr)\Bigr)^{1/2}$ ?

Comment: why not, i mean if you look how $\|A\|_2$ is defined, it makes sense.

Comment: $C=AB$ has $(i,j)$ element equal to $c_{ij}=\sum_t a_{it} b_{tj}$.  By your definition of the matrix norm hence $\|C\|^2 = \sum_{ij} c_{ij}^2 = \sum_{ij} (\sum_t a_{it} b_{tj})^2$.